# How to get Current position of a control on Win Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Am trying very hard but not find any method to get the location(x,y) of the control like picturebox on the form .. please help me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use  `picturebox1.Left` as you `X`  and `picturebox1.Top` as your `Y`
or

you can  combine `PointToScreen` and `PointToClient`:

```
Point locationOnForm = control.FindForm().PointToClient(
    control.Parent.PointToScreen(picturebox1.Location));
```